# unbale to delete item in codeigniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, crud, delete-row, codeigniter-4

controller

```
function delete($userId){

        $this->load->model('Prac_model');

        $this->Prac_model->getUser($userId);
        $this->Prac_model->delete($userId);
   redirect(base_url().'index.php/prac');
      }
```

model

```
  function getUser($userId){
   $this->db->where('id',$userId);
   $user=$this->db->get('prac')->row_array();
   return $user;
      }


 function delete($userId){
   $this->db->where('id',$userId);
   $this->db->delete('prac');
    }
```

view

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/prac/delete/'.$users['id'];   ?>">Delete</a></td>
```

when i am trying to delete its giving this error
404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

Comment: can you send the exact url been created after clicking on delete?

Comment: did you added the path in route ?

Comment: problem is solved base_url was not set properly